# What design pattern would be most appropriate

Tags: design-patterns

Suppose we have a set of several service classes (A,B,C,D,E,F), and the number of classes is quite large and may change. There are also classes that use them. First, i don't want to write long constructors. Secondly, for example, a new service class appears today, then it needs to be added to classes A, B, C, and tomorrow another service class, which is used by D, E, F. What design pattern would be most appropriate in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract Factory pattern looks good:

[image: Abstract Factory]

It allows you to have two layers of independence:

- The classes using A, B, C, D, E, F would be "Client".
- You can group A, B, C, D, E, F classes by "Product" A or B.
- You can add association from your products (A1, B1, A2, ...) to whatever you want, even Factory produced objects.

Depending on your exact need, and if in C++, you might take a look at templates to have common code (with for example templated member).

Comment: Great! Thank You!